# How to create friendship mapping in hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

This demo has 2 classes:

*User.java*:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String about;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friend")
    private Set<User> friends;
}
```

*Friendship.java*:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(Friendship.class)
public class Friendship {
    @Id @ManyToOne User friend;
    private String level;
}
```

Now the above gives error:

```
mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.example.demo.domain.User.friend in com.example.demo.domain.User.friends
```

In other words, I am trying to create `ManyToMany` mapping to itself (User can have many other users as friends) and adding extra information (the level property) so I need to create join table myself (because of the extra property). I was trying to implement it according to this [Hibernate Many to Many Mapping with Additional Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881264/hibernate-many-to-many-mapping-with-additional-column), which unfortunatelly doesn't say much about self mapping. So how to solve this issue?

PS: I have changed `User.java`:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String about;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friend")
    private Set<Friendship> friends;
}
```

So there is a set of friendship instead of users, however, in the custom join table `Friendship.java`, there is no information about the original user (there is no user_id in addition to friend_id). So I would need to make the User entity as composite id in the `Friendship`, but how to mapped that?

Comment: Consider upvoting / accepting if you find the answer helpful :>

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `friendship` table that joins `friend1` and `friend2`:

```
create table friendship (
    friend1 integer references friend,
    friend2 integer references friend
)
```

You can map it without `Friendship` by using `@ManyToMany`:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String about;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "friendship",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend1"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend2")
    )
    private List<User> friends;
}
```

---

If you want to stick to `Friendship` class and `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne`, then you still need two friends in your `Friendship` (just like in table definition):

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String about;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "friend1)
    private List<Friendship> friendships;
}

@Entity
public class Friendship {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "friend1",
        referencedColumnName = "id"
    )
    User friend1;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "friend2",
        referencedColumnName = "id"
    )
    User friend2;
}
```

---

The downside is that `friendship` table differentiates between left and right friends (`friend1` and `friend2`). To solve it, you would have to duplicate the rows with these ids swapped. Other solution would be to introduce a getter and map it two-way (example using `@ManyToMany`):

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String about;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "friendship",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend1"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend2")
    )
    private List<User> friends1;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "friendship",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend2"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "friend1")
    )
    private List<User> friends2;

    public Set<User> getFriends() {
        return Stream.concat(friends1.stream(), friends2.stream())
            .collect(toSet());
    }
}
```